# Editable polyline connecting every point in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I am trying to draw editable polyline that connects all points I click on using Google Maps API V3.

For example, after clicking on 4 different points on the map there should be 6 lines connecting all 4 points, while making these lines editable.

I have found this example ( http://www.ekelschot.eu/demo/maps/enableEditing.html ) which does create editable lines but there would only be 3 lines in case of 4 points.

Could I get some help as to how to do this please? I am very new to javascript, please excuse my ignorance on this matter.

Thank you.

Code of the example above: http://snipplr.com/view/38270/google-maps-api-v3--enableediting-polylines/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at using the [Drawing tools](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools) that were recently released?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you point me to an example where drawing manager is used for connecting all points please?